# How to do search function with one textbox and search for values in many columns of the mysql db using php codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to create a search function in a way that users can write all the keywords on a textbox
(just like Google search) ex :-  Cars in Japan, Used cars in Japan.  In this second example we can identify three keywords which belong to different columns in Item table in my DB.  ex :-  "Used" keyword from condition column, "cars" keyword from category column and "Japan" keyword from location column. Currently I'm using two drop down lists to select location and category. And check boxes to select condition. So I want to take these all keywords with one textbox. please help..!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the contents of the search bar into a php var ($inputRaw for example).

```
$inputRaw = $_POST[yourSearchBox]; // capture the raw user search input
```

From there you can clean it up a bit:

```
$InputRawArr = $searchResultsArr = array();

// process raw input
// trim any extra spaces outside the string
// then remove any double spaces inbetween the search terms         
$inputRaw = str_replace('  ', ' ', trim($inputRaw)); 

// separate each search term into an array
            $inputRawArr = explode(' ', $inputRaw);
            $inputRawArr = array_filter($inputRawArr);
```

So now if a user has entered 'used cars in Japan', you will end up with:

```
$inputRawArr =
[0] = 'used',
[1] = 'cars',
[2] = 'in',
[3] = 'Japan'
```

From here you should be able to create some logic to search the $inputRawArr for the strings relevant to your desired result. Checkout [Php's in_array function for this part](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

So if 'used' in array $inputRawArr, then set that part of the query true. Same with 'car'.

Do determine if a location ('Japan') is selected, I would cycle the $inputRawArr contents against a list of the possible locations. If one or more cells matches one of the locations in the list, then store those $inputRawArr cells into a PHP generated WHERE clause for location.

Comment: Your sanitization fails if I enter `blah       blah`. It's not enough to just turn two spaces into one space; that way just turns 4 spaces into 2. You need to turn 2 *or more* spaces into one space.

Comment: True, but I remedied that with array_filter() to remove any instances of more than double space. So if a user enters blah    blah the array will store it as [0] = 'blah', [1] = ' ', [2] = 'blah'. Then array_filter() will only return cells [0] = 'blah' and [1] = 'blah' It's probably bad practice, though.

Comment: Thank you all...!! And I got the answer to split a String by any number of white spaces  -  $inputRaw = preg_split('/\s+/', $searchText);